# Trying to click an asp:LinkButton with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, click

I am looking for a way to click an `<asp:LinkButton>` using jQuery. I am also using a `<asp:ModalPopupExtender>`, with a Yes/No option, so if the user clicks 'yes', it triggers a javascript function, `OnOk()`, which will have to click the save button on the page, but it is not doing anything at the moment, just showing the alert box:

**ASP.NET AJAX**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="butSaveAssociation" runat="server" OnClientClick="SaveAssociation();" Text="btnSave" />

<asp:ModalPopupExtender BehaviorID="confirmPopup" ID="confirmPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="butTest" 
    PopupControlID="ConfirmView"  OnOkScript="OnOk();" OnCancelScript="$find('confirmPopup').hide(); return false;" OkControlID="yesButton" CancelControlID="noButton" />

<asp:Panel ID="ConfirmView" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display:none; height:150px; width:250px;">
    <center><div>
        <table style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" align="left" style="padding-left: 75px; padding-top: 10px;">
                    Are you sure you want to save the changes?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <br /><br />
            <tr>
                <td align="left" colspan="1">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="yesButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="YesNoButton" BorderStyle="none" Text="YES">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
                <td align="right" colspan="1">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="noButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="YesNoButton" BorderStyle="none" Text="NO">
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div></center>
</asp:Panel>
```

**JAVASCRIPT W/ JQUERY**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnOk() {
        ClickSaveButton();
    }

    function ClickSaveButton() {
        $('#<%=butSaveAssociation.ClientID %>').click()  // not working...
        alert('save button clicked.');
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

The 'SaveAssociation()' function is simply to change a flag, so it does not perform the actual save:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SaveAssociation() {
        setDirty(false);
    }

    function setDirty(changeVal) {
        $("#IsDirty").val(changeVal);
    }
</script>

<input type="hidden" id="IsDirty" value="" />
```

This feature is simply to check if there has been changes on the page, if there has been changes, the 'IsDirty' hidden field will be set to true. I need to invoke the VB handler that handles 'butSaveAssociation.Click' if the user clicks 'OK' to save the changes, like a postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would just call Save Association as Joe mentioned. However, for future reference the following selector should give you better results.

```
$('[id$=butSaveAssociation]').click();
```

Neals select will also work if you are not using a master page, but I assume you are since you were trying to get the ClientID.

Comment: To get the correct ID, I ended up doing this: $('a[id$="butSaveAssociation"]').attr("ID");

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just call SaveAssociation() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function ClickSaveButton() {
    $('#butSaveAssociation').trigger('click');
    alert('save button clicked.');
}
```

Comment: Since he was trying to get the clientId of the button, I believe he is using master pages which mangles the id. Therefore, that selector would not work.

Comment: True, the actual ID of the button is 'ctl05_butSaveAssociation' and depends on the total number of controls.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem which I've worked around by the following:

```
function clickButton(element)
{
    if (element !=null)
    {
        if (element.click)
        {
            //IE only
            element.click();
        }
        else
        {
            var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //oops..        
    }
}
```

Called like this:

```
clickButton(document.getElementById('<%=butSaveAssociation.ClientID%>'));
```

I've got no idea why the jquery doesn't work though.

This looks like it should be fine but doesn't work for me either:

```
$('#<%=butSaveAssociation.ClientID %>').click();
```

It's probably something to do with cosmic radiation or the tides.. ;-)